# With Timber, can a child theme force pages from the parent theme to use its layouts?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I am creating a child theme based on a custom Timber theme I created. I like that the child theme inherit much of the parent's theme Timber functionality. But I'm running into the following issue. I would like to tell pages in the parent theme to use the child theme's base layout.

In both themes, I use the following layout:

```
templates\
   _layouts\
      base.twig
```

I still want pages in the parent theme to be accessible. My hope would be that the when a parent pages extends the base.twig layout (ie `{% extend '_layouts/base.twig' %}` ) I would like that base.twig theme to be the child theme's not the parent's.

Is this possible to do in `function.php` or using some other method?

Is there a way to tell Timber that

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it may help someone.

By default, Timber is checking the folders in order for templates.
Depending on how, and where you're calling `Timber::Render`, your folders may look different, but it will be something like this.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(46) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/child-theme/"
  [0]=>
  string(52) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/child-theme/views/"
  [0]=>
  string(38) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/parent-theme/"
  [0]=>
  string(44) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/parent-theme/views/"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "/"
}
```

I'm not sure why the root dir is in this array, it might be something to do with my setup but I had issues if I remove it.

It's looking for folders in the root of the child theme first, followed by its views folder, then falls through to the parent theme if a template could not be located.

This makes sense as it allows us to override a template in the parent theme by simply creating one in the child theme in the same location and with the same name; however, when we come to extend a template from the parent theme, we run into issues if we have overridden that template:

`{% extend '_layouts/base.twig' %}`

this will extend `_layouts/base.twig` in the child theme if it exists, or in the parent theme if not. This may not necessarily be what you want in all cases. Worse Still, if you try to extend a parent theme's counterpart in the child theme, you'll get an out-of-memory error as the template continually tries to extend itself rather than its parent.

The solution is to add the `themes` folder to the locations array in which Twig will search for templates. This will allow you to be more specific in which template you intended to extend.

```
function my_twig_template_paths( $paths ) {
    $paths[] = realpath( get_template_directory() . '/../' );
    return $paths;
}

add_filter( 'timber/loader/paths', __NAMESPACE__ . '\my_twig_template_paths' );
```

Now your locations array will look like this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(46) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/child-theme/"
  [0]=>
  string(52) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/child-theme/views/"
  [0]=>
  string(38) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/parent-theme/"
  [0]=>
  string(44) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/parent-theme/views/"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "/"
  [5]=>
  string(32) "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/" // <-- themes folder added
}
```

With that done, we can be more specific about the template to extend:

Extend parent theme template

```
{% extends theme.parent_slug ~ '/_layouts/base.twig' %}
```

Extend the child theme template

```
{% extends theme.slug ~ '/_layouts/base.twig' %}
```

Extend child, **or** parent theme template depending on whether or not the template exists in the child theme

```
{% extends '_layouts/base.twig' %}
```